# How to setup a bare git repository on a server to clone per ssh?

Tags: git, ssh

So I am actually pretty familiar with git. But I've never setup my own git *server*. So the following should be pretty much self-explaining.

Anyway: I want to checkout my get repo per ssh on my windows client. But I get an error which says the repo either does not exist or I have sufficient permissions. Actually I have permissions on the repo and the repo does exist. I'm not sure where my problem is. I can ssh into the server from my client.

server (linux)

```
$ whoami
foo
$ mkdir /git/myrepo && cd /git/myrepo
$ git --bare init
```

client (windows with cmder/conemu)

```
# user foo is in group git
$ git clone ssh://foo@myserver/git/myrepo myclone
Cloning into 'myclone'...
foo@myserver's password:
fatal: '/git/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

I also tried the git protocol - but since I'm not very familiar with this protocol I just switched to ssh

```
$ git clone git://myserver/git/myrepo myclone
Cloning into 'myclone'...
fatal: unable to connect to myserver:
myserver[0: 192.168.178.50]: errno=No error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot clone it as there is nothing in the repo yet.

what you have to do is init locally, commit something (1st commit), add remote and push to the repo.

Here is a full example:

http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/

Comment: Yeah that works fine for me with ssh. But not for the git protocol. Any ideas? Anyway, accepted.

Comment: By default the awfully-wide-open `git://` (git-daemon) server runs awfully wide open.  As a result it restricts exports of repositories to those with a `git-daemon-export-ok` file (doesn't matter what, if anything, is in it, it just has to exist).  You can also add options like `--base-path` to limit where it will look for repositories, but they still need to have the file, unless you add `--export-all`.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly specified the path to your repository. Try:

```
$ git clone ssh://foo@myserver:/git/myrepo myclone
                              ^^^
```

Server:

```
$ whoami
foo
$ mkdir /repo
$ cd /repo
$ git init --bare
```

Client:

```
$ git clone ssh://foo@localhost:/repo
```

Comment: I want to use an absolute path tho. The `:` way is to use a relative way afaik.